# How read the data in a spark DF when column name changes and data type changes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a parquet data with the following schema ,

```
Id:int,
Name:String
```

On a later stage new incoming data schema got changed to

```
Id:double/long,
NAME:String
```

1. Change in type
2. Change in Field name

I have both of the parquet schema  data in the same folder .How I can read both of the schema in `spark.read.format("parquet").load("")`?

Any expert advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in this scenario, I would create a v2 of this table and segregate my parquet files. Technically these are two different tables.

If you need to tie them back together, you can then create a second layer and stream both of these tables into a new table.

Answer (score 0):

In a one time scenario, it is suggested to cast the datatype & rewrite the target parquet file.

```
scala> val  df = Seq((1, "as"), (2, "fd")).toDF("a", "b")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: string]

scala> df.show
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1| as|
|  2| fd|
+---+---+

scala> df.withColumn("a", $"a".cast("double")).show
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|1.0| as|
|2.0| fd|
+---+---+
```

If not then you need to update the source system with the same logic